# Using Excel PasteSpecial (Divide) on Row Count which varies

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I have a spreadsheet as follows:

- Columns A:G (Name, Path, Size, Type, DateCreated, DateLastModified, DateLast Accessed)
- Header uses rows 1:7
- ColumnC contains file size in KB
- Primary VBA populates from selected folder
- Sub inserts 2 columns to left of ColumnD
- Columns now: Name, Path, Size in KB, Size in MB, Size in GB, Type, DateCreated, DateLastModified, DateLast Accessed

I have a Sub to call which loops ColumnC to and inserts a divided amount into ColumnD & ColumnE

Looping works but takes time so would like to PasteSpecial where ColumnD = ColumnC/1000000 and ColumnE = ColumnC/1000000000

Each folder will have different quantities of files.  To run the conversion Call I am using `myRows = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row - 7` (where 7 is the header-row deduction)"

I would like to PasteSpecial the myRows of ColumnC to ColumnD and ColumnE but, as noted myRows will be different for each folder.  I am not finding (but still searching) where to put the divisor which will be used for the ColumnD and ColumnE calculation with:

```
PasteSpecial Operation:=xlPastSpecialOperationDivide
```

My Call code is:

```
Sub Convert_MB_GB()

    Dim myRows As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim var As Double
    Dim Num1 As Long
    Dim Num2 As Long
    Num1 = 1000000 'Divisor for KB to MB
    Num2 = 1000000000 'Divisor for KB to GB

        myRows = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row - 7 'Count rows and subtract 7-row header

        Range("D:E").Insert 'Insert 2 columns to the left of Column D
        [D7].Value = "Size in MB" 'Add title to column
        [E7].Value = "Size in GB" 'Add title to column

        Range("C8").Select 'Starting Cell

        For x = 1 To myRows
            var = Application.ActiveCell.Value
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
                ActiveCell.Value = var / Num1
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
                ActiveCell.Value = var / Num2
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
        Next

 Range("D:D").NumberFormat = "0.0" 'Configure Column D to 1 decimal point
 Range("E:E").NumberFormat = "0.0" 'Configure Column E to 1 decimal point

End Sub
```

Comment: No need to try to `PasteSpecial` here. Really would [advise against using `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Also, you could either do the calculations with a formula, and then hard-code the values, or do the calcs in memory with a Variant array.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
Sub x()

Dim myRows As Long

myRows = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row - 7

With Cells(1, 1000)
    .Value = 1000000 'some out of the way unused cell
    Range("D8").Resize(myRows).Value = Range("C8").Resize(myRows).Value
    .Copy
    Range("D8").Resize(myRows).PasteSpecial operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationDivide
    .ClearContents
End With

End Sub
```

---

Or another approach

```
Sub x()

Dim myRows As Long

myRows = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row - 7

With Range("D8").Resize(myRows)
    .Value = .Offset(, -1).Value
    .Value = Evaluate(.Address & "/1000000")
    'or in one line
    '.Value = Evaluate(.Offset(, -1).Address & "/1000000")
End With

End Sub
```

See [here](https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/avoid-loop-for-range-calculations-evaluate/).

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to `PasteSpecial` and you should avoid using `Select`.  Your loop can be simplified to:

```
    For x = 8 To myRows
        var = Cells(x,3)
        Cells(x,4) = var / Num1
        Cells(x,5) = var / Num2
    Next x
```

This will work much faster than selecting.  You can also turn off `ScreenUpdating` and turn `Calculation` to manual while executing your code.